# Jekyll generates empty files

Tags: jekyll

I recently pulled a copy of my github pages site to a new Windows machine and when I run `jekyll` all the files get created in `_site` but any that use a layout are empty.

I have tried `jekyll build --layouts C:\Path\to\site\_layouts` which still resulted in empty files.

Its compiling SASS no problem and copying the files with no front matter. Its generating empty files for all the posts and drafts so its seeing `_posts` and `_drafts` which makes me think it should be able to see `_layouts` but its not...

anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Can you post your _config.yml? And maybe your directory structure?